# Payments app with scheduled tasks and outstanding payments

Tags: android, productivity, finance, app, android-app

I am looking for an app that would allow you to organize payments, carried out with either cash or through interac, to a variety of people or institutions (hereby referred to as payees).

Suppose you need to pay somebody. It may be that the payee is a person that comes regularly to your home to do cleaning chores (periodic, flexible, service time variant, periodic scheduled event). It may be that the person may be a hydraulic or electrician or water boiler maintenance person which comes to your home once in a while, when things break (unforseen event), or for a checkup (periodic event). It may be that the person is someone that comes to your home to pick up your children and takes them to a supervision and play place (scheduled, fixed time, flexible scheduling, with payment taking place each time the child returns) or school (periodic scheduling, with payment taking place once per semester). It may also be that a person goes to a store, such as a supermarket or farmacy or photograph shop or takeaway place and needs to pay (but, may not have received payment on their account, and may be without bank money or cash, and, just like in all other scenarios, might need for the person receiving the payment to keep track of the money due, creating, for the payer, a bunch of outstanding payments, of various amounts).

Another type of payment could be an insurance for a car, or an amount a child has asked for a car or for some ceremony or other purpose. There are already vendor specific apps to take care of bills, which can be periodically checked.

So, one needs an app, to:

- Schedule a service, which another person or institution is to carry out to oneself. The service may be scheduled a number of times. If the number of times is many, the user must have an in app mechanism to schedule or delete repeated times into the future in one go, or move them. They must also be able to specify the time period for the service.
- They must be able to input the amount of money due.

When the service is done, the user enters a password to place a checkmark that the service was done.

When the user pays any amount, they are able to select to whom. The app selects the events the user needs to pay for (the user can pay for advance service, carrying out a payment into the future, or, the user may pay for concluded jobs, which may also go far back). The app, then displays the tasks performed and the corresponding payments.

The user can also modify the time period for a task.

The user must remember to use the app to keep track of what is due, and whether it was paid or not.

The user can also add notes to each payee or task, where they can specify, for example, when the amounts would be due, and what these tasks are.

With all these payments to remember, it could be easy to forget to pay or to forget how much is due or that a particular task is coming up. However, by looking at the app, regularly (and inputting the stuff), one could keep track of all of this.

I would be willing to pay for such an app.

Has anyone implemented it?

When will such an app be available?

Has anyone looked into this?

Thank you for your contributions.

Thanks.